# Difference between hook_services_services and hook_services_resources

Tags: 7, hooks, services

I'm doing this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-drupal-web-service-project/) to get familiar with the concepts of the Services module. In that tutorial, you implement a custom service for the Services module. Therefore it uses `hook_services_services`. But there are other tutorials (e.g. [An introduction to Drupal 7 RESTful Services](http://www.pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-drupal-7-restful-services)) that use `hook_services_resources` for the same thing. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first article is incorrect, there is no `hook_services_services()` (at least not according to any documentation for the services module, nor in my experience).

The correct hook to use is [`hook_services_resources()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!services.services.api.php/function/hook_services_resources/6). See the docs/services.services.api.php file included with the module for full details.

Comment: What about this: http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/services/services--user_service--user_service.module/function/user_service_service/7

Comment: Also wrong - there is no `hook_services_services()` or `hook_service()` in the Services module. That file doesn't even exist any more, those docs are woefully out of date

Comment: Could you please point me to a working example with detailed instructions? Whatever I try it doesn't work. I just can't find a working example.

Comment: You'll find a working example in the module itself, in the docs/services.services.api.php file. I can confirm that example works perfectly, I've used it as a base for dozens of projects over the years